# Can't change image to video camera when button clicked

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

i am new to python and flask and i want to a facemask detection in webapp. But, i faced some problems which is i cannot change the image to video camera when button clicked. Is there anything wrong with my code. Below is my html and python code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script>
        
            function stop(){
                $("#ciao").attr("src", "/static/1.png");
                $("#stop").attr("class","btn btn-danger active");
                $("#start").attr("class","btn btn-outline-success");
            }
            function start(){
                $("#ciao").attr("src", "{{url_for('video')}}");
                $("#start").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
                $("#stop").attr("class","btn btn-outline-danger");
            }
        
                </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="">
        <button id="start" onclick= "start()" class="btn btn-outline-success"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> start</button>
        <button id = "stop" onclick="stop()" class="btn btn-danger active"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i> Stop</button> 
    </div>
        <img id ="ciao" class ="image1" src="/static/1.png">
    </body>
```

App.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,Response
from cameraDetection import Video
app = Flask(__name__)
output=[]
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/FaceMaskDetection_HomePage')
def homepage():
    return render_template("FaceMaskDetection_HomePage.html",result = output)
def gen(camera):
    while True:
    frame=camera.get_frame()
     yield(b'--frame\r\n'
     b'Content-Type:  image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame +
     b'\r\n\r\n')
@app.route('/video')
    def video():
     return Response(gen(Video()),
      mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
app.run(debug=True)
```

cameraDetection.py

```
import cv2
class Video(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  def __del__(self):
    self.video.release()
  def get_frame(self):
    ret,frame=self.video.read()
    ret,jpg=cv2.imencode('.jpg',frame)
    return jpg.tobytes()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: maybe first use `print()` in Python and `console.log()` in JavaScript to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. If you get errors when you run flask in console then you should show it in question (not in comments) as text. And the same with errors in JavaScript console in browser (but this can be as image)

Comment: if you want to run it on server (not on local computer) then you can't use `VideoCapture(0)` because it will try to access webcam connected directly to server - and it will need to use JavaScript to access local webcam and send image to server. like in example on GitHub [furas / python-examples / flask / web camera in browser - canvas - take image and upload to server](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/flask/web%20camera%20in%20browser%20-%20canvas%20-%20take%20image%20and%20upload%20to%20server)

Comment: you forgot to load `jQuery` in `HTML`. You can't use `$(...)` without `jQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fogot to load `jQuery` in `HMTL`. You can't use `$(...)` without `jQuery`.

For example:

```js
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

After adding `jQuery` code works for me.

---

I put all in one file so everyone can simply copy and test it.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template_string, Response
import cv2

class Video:
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        
    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()
        
    def get_frame(self):
        ret, frame = self.video.read()
        ret, jpg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        return jpg.tobytes()

app = Flask(__name__)
output = []

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
              b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n'
              b'\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/FaceMaskDetection_HomePage')
def homepage():
    return render_template_string("""
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function stop(){
        $("#ciao").attr("src", "/static/1.png");
        $("#stop").attr("class","btn btn-danger active");
        $("#start").attr("class","btn btn-outline-success");
    }
    function start(){
        $("#ciao").attr("src", "{{url_for('video')}}");
        $("#start").attr("class","btn btn-success active");
        $("#stop").attr("class","btn btn-outline-danger");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="">
    <button id="start" onclick="start()" class="btn btn-outline-success"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i> start</button>
    <button id="stop" onclick="stop()" class="btn btn-danger active"><i class="fa fa-stop"></i> Stop</button> 
  </div>
  <img id="ciao" class="image1" src="/static/1.png">
</body>
    
""")

@app.route('/video')
def video():
     return Response(gen(Video()),
                     mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    
# --- main ---    

app.run(debug=True)
```

---

**EDIT:**

I found two different problems.

1. If you use `Video()` in `def video()` then second user (or second browser on your computer) may have problem to access camera because it will try open the same webcam - and it will generate error that webcam is already used. You may have to create `Video()` only once at start as global variable and later use this variable inside `def video()`
2. All this will work only on local computer because when you will run it on server then `cv2` will try to access webcam directly connected to server. It can't access remotly user's webcam. Only web browser on user's computer may have acccess to user's webcam - and this may need JavaScript to get image from user's webcam, send it to server, and get image with changes - like in my example on GitHub
   [furas / python-examples / flask / web camera in browser - canvas - take image and upload to server](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/flask/web%20camera%20in%20browser%20-%20canvas%20-%20take%20image%20and%20upload%20to%20server)